# Customising or subclassing a CocoaPod library

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, cocoapods, subclassing

The problem can be simplified like this: our library has 3 view controllers - `MainController`, `SecondController`, `ThirdController`. `MainController` is what we create an instance of in our personal project; it has a button that transitions to `SecondController` which has a button that transitions to `ThirdController`. `ThirdController` has a button that is hooked up to a method:

```
-(void)buttonPressed{
    NSLog("Button has been pressed!");
}
```

Let's assume that `MainController` imports `SecondController.h`, and `SecondController` imports `ThirdController.h`.

We want to keep the library unchanged except for overriding `buttonPressed` so that it presents a view controller from our personal project, so we subclass `ThirdController` as `CustomThirdController` and override `buttonPressed` to do what we want. If we now import `MainController.h` to our project and create an instance of `MainController`, it will not be using our new `CustomThirdController` subclass. How do we use our subclass without subclassing all 3 controllers from our library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fork it and change it, introduce delegate or add more options for customization. If you improve it you can send a pull request back to author.

Update:

For monkey patching, use category in case if you want to replace a single method in existing class.

In the worst case you can resort to method swizzling.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to improve the library, just make it so that it's customised for my project. I've updated my question so that it makes more sense.

Comment: If you want monkey patch you can use category instead of subclass. In that case classes remain untouched except that you replace existing method of class with your own.